# How can I get Django application name for a file inside that application?

Tags: django

Having full path for the file that is a part of django application I would like to get a Django application name.

For example for this path:

```
/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/auth_backends.py
```

Application name is `auth`.

I wonder how this Django application name could be programatically calculated for specific filename inside an app.

Background: I want to integrate calling Django test management command from a vim editor. It should run tests for an app currently edited file belongs.

Answer (score 3):

You can get module by filename with [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__). You can get it's package name with `__package__` attribute. Then you can check which app from `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` is a substring of package name. It's your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, __import__ with given filename does not work in Python 2.6. (http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#porting-to-python-2-6)

Comment: @bmihelac You are right. Use [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) module instead.

Comment: also, ``__package__`` is ``django`` instead of expected ``auth``

Comment: Would have to digg into imp module to see if it can be used

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of a class in that module you could try:

```
instance._meta.app_label
```